# Open source or free software for flow-chart and database-table connection visualisation?

Tags: database-design, visualization

I would like to ask you to tell me, what visualisation software to take.
Normally I would use a vector illustation software like "inkscape", but I would like to use a software, where I don't have to draw the lines manually and where I can use the symbols withouth drawing them by myself :)

so, do you know good software, that I can take for flow-charts and database tables?
I prefer open source or at least freeware.

Thank you in advance, Andreas

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181829/best-free-flowchart-software among many, many others.

Answer (score 1):

[Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) is a drawing program similar to Visio.  It has a large number of templates, and you can take a quick look at the [examples](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) to see the sort of things it can do.

I've used it for UML diagrams and it's fine (a little clunky compared to Visio, but at least it's free!).  It definitely supports database tables (entity diagrams) and flow charts.

Answer (score 1):

For open source graph visualization try [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Answer (score 0):

To reverse-engineer a database schema, try DbVisualizer: http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/.

For more general drawing of UML, try Green: http://green.sourceforge.net/.